# How to know which word is clicked in a article in Flutter

Tags: flutter, text, dart, click, textselection

I'm tring to using Flutter to building a reading application, where I want users to tap in the article and the word clicked will be highlighted. Is there a way to know which child is clicked in flutter? Or I have to using a list of Textspan to achieve that.